# Printing Jan, Feb, March and April of 2020 with Cal

Tags: brace-expansion, cal

I learnt brace expansion today and tried the following command

```
$ cal {1...4} 2020
```

I expected the output to display the calendar of Jan, Feb, March and April for the year 2020. But I got the following log

```
Usage: cal [general options] [-jy] [[month] year]
       cal [general options] [-j] [-m month] [year]
       ncal -C [general options] [-jy] [[month] year]
       ncal -C [general options] [-j] [-m month] [year]
       ncal [general options] [-bhJjpwySM] [-H yyyy-mm-dd] [-s country_code] [[month] year]
       ncal [general options] [-bhJeoSM] [year]
General options: [-31] [-A months] [-B months] [-d yyyy-mm]
```

Comment: (a) Too many dots -- it only takes 2 in the brace expression. (b) cal only processes 2 args -- you can't feed it `1 2 3 4 2020`. Use a bash loop `for m in {1..4}`.

Comment: @ Paul_Pedant Thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stuff arguments into a command if it is not part of their syntax. `cal {1...4} 2020` expands to `cal 1 2 3 4 2020` and that is invalid. The manual page of call says that `-m X` selects the month X in this year and `-A Y` displays Y months after it. Therefore,

```
cal -m1 -A3
```